# Lazy fetching an association mapped as non-lazy

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity with a one-to-many association defined for it and 'lazy' attribute is set to 'false' for it in the mapping file.

In most of the cases, this is the behavior I want. But for a specific use case, I don't want the associations to be loaded. So changing the mapping file is out of my options.

Using HQL or Criteria API, is there a way that I can query only for parent object without loading the association? Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an option to change your approach so by default your collection is lazy loaded and in special cases it's loaded eagerly?

Comment: I do not have an option to change it..

Comment: you may want to read through [this link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies). Specifically the section on "Programmatically override or completely redefine fetching at runtime through API and queries". setFetchMode is your friend I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Aishwarya. But in my  case, though I override it in Criteria API, it is still fetching the association eagerly.

Comment: @PrasanthNath, are you sure? do you see the query getting fired when you do a show sql = true ? it would be very surprising if thats the case :-)

Comment: Yeah, am sure. Have tested it again and it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that this can be achieved by using Criteria API in Hibernate 4.0 release.